# sql server import wizard data conversion

Tags: sql-server, csv, importerror

I keep getting this error when running import wizard for a csv file

```
Error 0xc02020c5: Data Flow Task 1: Data conversion failed while converting column "Column    45" (190) to column "Column 45" (2352).
```

Column 45 is a numeric(25,0) null

the data in column 45 are either integers ranging from 0-10 or null and the first 10+ lines are showing up as blanks.

here is the create table statement I used:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[FA_SUB_KPI5](
    [D_DTM] [datetime] NULL,
    [TECHNOLOGY] [varchar](5) NULL,
    [VOICEDATA] [varchar](8) NULL,
    [MRKT_NM] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [REGION_NM] [varchar](15) NULL,
    [CLUSTER_NM] [varchar](60) NULL,
    [BSC_NM] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [BTS_ID] [int] NULL,
    [CSCD_NM] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [SECT_SEQ_ID] [int] NULL,
    [BND_ID] [int] NULL,
    [FA_ID] [int] NULL,
    [TCE_DTCT_CALL_SETUP_F_CNT] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [MS_ACQ_CALL_SETUP_F_CNT] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [SIGN_CALL_SETUP_F_CNT] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [BAD_FRM_CALL_SETUP_F_CNT] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [REORG_ATT_CNT] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [TCE_CALL_SETUP_F_CNT] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [WCD_CALL_SETUP_F_CNT] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [L_CALL_SETUP_F_CNT] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [TRAF_FRM_MISS_CNT] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [BCP_TMO_CALL_SETUP_F_CNT] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [PWR_CALL_SETUP_F_CNT] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [SDU_EXCP_CALL_SETUP_F_CNT] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [SDU_RSPNS_CALL_SETUP_F_CNT] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CMP_OVLD_CALL_SETUP_F_CNT] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [A1P_OOS_CALL_SETUP_F_CNT] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [BS_CALL_SETUP_F_CNT] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [BS_CONT_CALL_SETUP_F_CNT] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [MSC_TMO_CALL_SETUP_F_CNT] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [SVC_NEGO_CALL_SETUP_F_CNT] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [SDU_IDL_FRM_CALL_SETUP_F_CNT] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [TCE_IDL_FRM_CALL_SETUP_F_CNT] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [BCP_OVLD_CALL_SETUP_F_CNT] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [BCP_CEP_TMO_CNT] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [BAD_FRM_RLS_BEFORE_CNCT_CNT] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [BAD_FRM_RLS_AFTER_CNCT_CNT] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [BS_RLS_BEFORE_CNCT_CNT] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [BS_RLS_AFTER_CNCT_CNT] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [TCE_RLS_BEFORE_CNCT_CNT] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [SDU_RLS_BEFORE_CNCT_CNT] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [MGW_RLS_BEFORE_CNCT_CNT] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [TCE_RLS_AFTER_CNCT_CNT] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [SDU_RLS_AFTER_CNCT_CNT] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [MGW_RLS_AFTER_CNCT_CNT] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [MBL_ACQ_CALL_SETUP_F_CNT] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [TCC_MSG_TMO_CNT] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [TCE_RQST_ERR_CNT] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [ATP_CALL_SETUP_F_CNT] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [RSRC_ALOC_ERR_CNT] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [DMC_MSG_TRANS_ERR_CNT] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [A8_CONN_SETUP_F_CNT] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [MBL_AUTHT_SCP_F_CNT] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [NW_SETUP_F_CNT] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [DMC_BRR_PATH_SET_TMO_CNT] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [L_LOST_CALL_F_CNT] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [HWR_ID_RSPNS_TMO_CNT] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [DSP_ALOC_TMO_CNT] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [DCC_CE_ALOC_F_CNT] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [ATT_CNT] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [AXS_F_CNT] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CE_BLK_CNT] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CUST_BLK_CNT] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [DRP_CALL_CNT] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [HHI_ATT_CNT] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [HHI_BAFRM_CNT] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [HHI_CALL_SETUP_SXS_CNT] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [MBL_ORG_CNT] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [MBL_TER_CNT] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [NON_BTS_EQ_BLK_CNT] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [PRIM_CALL_ERL] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [PWR_BLK_CNT] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [SFUL_CALL_CNT] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [SILENT_RETRY_CNT] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [T1_BHL_BLK_CNT] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [WCD_BLK_CNT] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [SMS_ATT_CNT] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [SMS_SXS_CNT] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CTRL_CH_USG_CNT] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CTRL_SL_USG_CNT] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [DO_SECT_PHL_FWD_PS_TMS] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [DO_SECT_PHL_REV_PS_TMS] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [EUSR_CONN_SETUP_ATT_CNT] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [EUSR_CONN_SETUP_F_CNT] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [FWD_D_TRANSD_QTY] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [MAC_ID_BLK_CNT] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [MAC_ID_UTIL_RT] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [MS_RQST_CNT] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [MS_RQST_D_QTY] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [NORM_CONN_CLS_CNT] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [NORM_SESS_RLS_CNT] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [RAB_SET_CNT] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [RCVD_RAB_CNT] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [REV_AIR_PER_BAD_FRM_CNT] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [REV_AIR_PER_TRSF_D_QTY] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [REV_D_TRANSD_QTY] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [RNC_BLK_CNT] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [SESS_ATT_CNT] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [SESS_CONF_SXS_CNT] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [SL_USG_CNT] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [MAX_USER_CNT] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [AVG_USER_CNT] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [MOU_TMS] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC0] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC1] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC2] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC3] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC4] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC5] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC6] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC7] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC8] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC9] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC10] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC11] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC12] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC13] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC14] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC15] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC16] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC17] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC18] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC19] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC20] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC21] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC22] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC23] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC24] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC25] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC26] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC27] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC28] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC29] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC30] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC31] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC32] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC33] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC34] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC35] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC36] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC37] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC38] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC39] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC40] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC41] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC42] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC43] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC44] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC45] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC46] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC47] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC48] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC49] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC50] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC51] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC52] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC53] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC54] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC55] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC56] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC57] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC58] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC59] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC60] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC61] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC62] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC63] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC64] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC65] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC66] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC67] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC68] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC69] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC70] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC71] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC72] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC73] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC74] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC75] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC76] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC77] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC78] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC79] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC80] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC81] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC82] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC83] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC84] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC85] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC86] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC87] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC88] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC89] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC90] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC91] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC92] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC93] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC94] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC95] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC96] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC97] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC98] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC99] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC100] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC101] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC102] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC103] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC104] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC105] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC106] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC107] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC108] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC109] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC110] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC111] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC112] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC113] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC114] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC115] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC116] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC117] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC118] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC119] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC120] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC121] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC122] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC123] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC124] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC125] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC126] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC127] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC1000] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC1001] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC1002] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC1003] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC2000] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC2001] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC2002] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC2003] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC2004] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC2005] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC2006] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC2007] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC2008] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC2009] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC2010] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC2011] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC2012] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC2013] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC2014] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC2015] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC2016] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC2017] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC2018] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC2019] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC2020] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC2021] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC2022] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC2023] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC2024] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC2025] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC2026] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC2027] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC2028] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC2029] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC2030] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC2031] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC2032] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC2033] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC2034] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC2035] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC2036] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC2037] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC2038] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC2039] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC2040] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC2041] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC2042] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC2043] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC2044] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC2045] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC2046] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC2047] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC2048] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC2049] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC2050] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC2051] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC2052] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC2053] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC2054] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC2055] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC2056] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC2057] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC2058] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC2059] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC2060] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC2061] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC2062] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC2063] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC2064] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC2065] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC2066] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC2067] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC2068] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC2069] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC2070] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC2071] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC2072] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC2073] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC2074] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC2075] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC2076] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC2077] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC2078] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC2079] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC2080] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC2081] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC2082] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC2083] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC2084] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC2085] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC2086] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC2087] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC2088] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC2089] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC2090] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC3000] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC3001] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC3002] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC3003] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC3004] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC3005] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC3006] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC3007] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC3008] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC3009] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC3010] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC3011] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC3012] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC3013] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC3014] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC3015] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC3016] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC3017] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC3018] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC3019] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC3020] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC3021] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC3022] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC6000] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC6001] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC6002] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC7000] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC7001] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC7002] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC7003] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC7004] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC7005] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC7006] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC7007] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC7008] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC7009] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC7010] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC7011] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC7012] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC7013] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC7014] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC7015] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC7016] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC7017] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC7018] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC7019] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC7020] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC7021] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC7022] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC7023] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC7024] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC7025] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC8000] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC8001] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC8002] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC8003] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC8004] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC8005] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC8006] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC8007] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC8008] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC8009] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC8010] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC8011] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC8012] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC8013] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC8014] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC8015] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC8016] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC8017] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC8018] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC8019] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC8020] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC8021] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC8022] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC8023] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC8024] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC8025] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC8026] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC8027] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC8028] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC8029] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC8030] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC8031] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC8032] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC8033] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC2091] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC2092] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC2093] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [CFC2094] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [R3_M_ATT_CNT] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [R3_M_SUC_CNT] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [R3_M_DRP_BAD_CNT] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [R3_V_PRIM_CALL_ERL] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [R3_V_MOU_TMS] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [R3_M_BTS_UNA_CNT] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [R3_M_SYN_TO_CNT] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [R3_M_NOT_ACQ_CNT] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [R3_M_HCM_TO_CNT] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [R3_M_BAD_FRM_CNT] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [R3_M_MSC_DRP_CNT] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [R3_M_ETC_FAIL_CNT] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [R3_M_MOB_REL_CNT] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [R3_M_MSC_CLR_CNT] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [R3_M_DRP_ETC_CNT] [numeric](25, 0) NULL,
    [BSM_ID] [int] NULL,
    [BSC_SEQ_ID] [int] NULL
)
```

and then here are some sample lines from the CSV:

```
11/17/2013 02:11:00,1XRTT,DATA,Minnesota,Region 10,Minnesota_ST CLOUD_CL#27,STC,1044,MS03NP423,0,1,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,19,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,18,1,0,.093888888888888888888888888888888888889,0,19,0,0,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,6,0,0,0,6,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,11,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
11/17/2013 02:11:00,1XRTT,VOICE,Minnesota,Region 10,Minnesota_ST CLOUD_CL#27,STC,1044,MS03NP423,0,1,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,.023055555555555555555555555555555555556,0,1,0,0,0,5,5,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,1.38333333333333333333333333333333333333,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,6,0,0,0,6,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,11,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,,
11/17/2013 02:11:00,1XRTT,VOICE,Minnesota,Region 10,Minnesota_ST CLOUD_CL#27,STC,1044,MS03NP423,0,1,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,19,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,18,1,0,.093888888888888888888888888888888888889,0,19,0,0,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,6,0,0,0,6,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,11,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
11/17/2013 02:11:00,1XRTT,DATA,Minnesota,Region 10,Minnesota_ST CLOUD_CL#27,STC,1044,MS03NP423,1,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,.036111111111111111111111111111111111111,0,5,0,0,0,7,7,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,2.16666666666666666666666666666666666667,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,6,0,0,0,12,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,,
11/17/2013 02:11:00,1XRTT,DATA,Minnesota,Region 10,Minnesota_ST CLOUD_CL#27,STC,1044,MS03NP423,1,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,12,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,7,5,0,.04,0,12,0,0,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,6,0,0,0,12,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
11/17/2013 02:11:00,1XRTT,VOICE,Minnesota,Region 10,Minnesota_ST CLOUD_CL#27,STC,1044,MS03NP423,1,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,.036111111111111111111111111111111111111,0,5,0,0,0,7,7,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,2.16666666666666666666666666666666666667,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,6,0,0,0,12,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,,
11/17/2013 02:11:00,1XRTT,VOICE,Minnesota,Region 10,Minnesota_ST CLOUD_CL#27,STC,1044,MS03NP423,1,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,12,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,7,5,0,.04,0,12,0,0,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,6,0,0,0,12,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
11/17/2013 02:11:00,1XRTT,DATA,Minnesota,Region 10,Minnesota_ST CLOUD_CL#27,STC,1044,MS03NP423,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,18,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,11,7,0,.627777777777777777777777777777777777778,0,18,0,0,0,82,82,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,37.6666666666666666666666666666666666667,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,57,0,0,0,53,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,19,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,,
11/17/2013 02:11:00,1XRTT,DATA,Minnesota,Region 10,Minnesota_ST CLOUD_CL#27,STC,1044,MS03NP423,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,32,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,20,12,0,.247777777777777777777777777777777777778,0,32,0,0,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,57,0,0,0,53,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,19,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
11/17/2013 02:11:00,1XRTT,VOICE,Minnesota,Region 10,Minnesota_ST CLOUD_CL#27,STC,1044,MS03NP423,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,18,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,11,7,0,.627777777777777777777777777777777777778,0,18,0,0,0,82,82,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,37.6666666666666666666666666666666666667,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,57,0,0,0,53,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,19,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,,
11/17/2013 02:11:00,1XRTT,VOICE,Minnesota,Region 10,Minnesota_ST CLOUD_CL#27,STC,1044,MS03NP423,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,32,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,20,12,0,.247777777777777777777777777777777777778,0,32,0,0,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,57,0,0,0,53,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,19,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to a Linux server, or "awk" for Windows, you could quickly check your data to see you have the correct number of fields all the way through your CSV...

```
awk -F, '{print NF}' yourCSV
```